# My Infix to postfix Code does not work

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation, infix-operator

I tried making my infix to postfix code, it works without the braces, but when I try to include the portion to account for braces, it crashes, here is the main part of the code:

```
for (i=0; i<characters.length; i++)
{
    if (characters[i]=='*' || characters[i]=='/' || characters[i]=='+' || characters[i]=='-' || characters[i]=='(' || characters[i]==')'){
        if (postfix.empty() && characters[i]!=')')
            postfix.push(characters[i]);
        else if (!postfix.empty()){
            if (characters[i]=='(')
                postfix.push(characters[i]);
            if (characters[i]=='*' || characters[i]=='/')
                priority2=1;
            if (characters[i]=='+' || characters[i]=='-')
                priority2=0;
            if (characters[i]==')'){
                while (postfix.peek()!='(') //loop until we see the closing bracket
                    System.out.print(postfix.pop()); //pop everything till we see the closing bracket
                postfix.pop(); //to pop the bracket
            }
            if (!postfix.empty())
                peeked=postfix.peek();
            if (peeked=='*' || peeked=='/')
                priority=1;
            if (peeked=='+' || peeked=='-')
                priority=0;
            if (priority2>priority)
                postfix.push(characters[i]);
            else{
                while (!postfix.empty())
                    System.out.print(postfix.pop());
                postfix.push(characters[i]);
            }       
        }
    }
    else 
        System.out.print(characters[i]);    
}
while (!postfix.empty())
    System.out.print(postfix.pop());
```

Any help would be appreciated. It breaks when it comes to a brace.

Comment: You should _really_ debug your own code.

Comment: I tried.. i went through it so many times.. I cant see why it would still print the braces out even though i'm popping them (before printing them)

Comment: Download and use a debugger.

Comment: The code does not have errors.. It is with the process

Comment: It doesn't work as intended? Then it has a bug and _you_ need to find it. Are you using Eclipse? [Here's how to debug in it.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Comment: A programmer must be able to debug his own bug. When you're going to work how can you post all your code and ask "Hey, what's the bug in my code". Just think where the bug may come from and break before it. Also, why don't use switch case?

Answer (score 0):

You can get some insight from my implementation of Infix To Postfix program, which is based on the standard algorithm for doing such conversions. Here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfixPostfix
{
  private Stack<Character> stack;
  private StringBuilder postfixExpression;

  public InfixPostfix()
  {
    stack = new Stack<>();
    postfixExpression = new StringBuilder();

    String infix = getInfixExpression();

    if (isValidInfix(infix))
    {
      System.out.println(convertToPostfix(infix));
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
    }
  }

  private boolean isValidInfix(String infix)
  {
    int parenthesisCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
    {
      char ch = infix.charAt(i);
      if (ch == '(')
        parenthesisCounter++;
      else if (ch == ')')
        parenthesisCounter--;

      if (parenthesisCounter < 0)
        return false;
    }
    if (parenthesisCounter == 0)
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  private String convertToPostfix(String infix)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
    {
      char ch = infix.charAt(i);

      switch (ch)
      {
        case '+':
        case '-':
          processOperatorOfPrecedence(ch, 1);
          break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
          processOperatorOfPrecedence(ch, 2);
          break;
        case '(':
          stack.push(ch);
          break;
        case ')':
          processParenthesis(ch);
          break;
        default:
          postfixExpression.append(ch);
          break;
      }
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
      postfixExpression.append(stack.pop());
    }

    return postfixExpression.toString();
  }

  private void processOperatorOfPrecedence(char operator, int precedence)
  {
    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
      char topOperator = stack.pop();

      if (topOperator == '(')
      {
        stack.push(topOperator);
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        int operatorPrecedence;

        if (topOperator == '+' || topOperator == '-')
          operatorPrecedence = 1;
        else
          operatorPrecedence = 2;

        if (operatorPrecedence < precedence)
        {
          stack.push(topOperator);
          break;
        }
        else
          postfixExpression.append(topOperator);
      }
    }
    stack.push(operator);
  }

  private void processParenthesis(char ch)
  {
    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
      char character = stack.pop();

      if (character == '(')
        break;
      else
        postfixExpression.append(character);
    }
  }

  private String getInfixExpression()
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an infix math expression: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();
    return input;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new InfixPostfix();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to scan it twice, once to establish validity and another time to parse it. You can do both at the same time, and the 'standard algorithm', i.e. the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm, does so.